# How do you get the current viewport position of a DOM element using Google's Closure library?

Tags: javascript, positioning, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am using Google's closure library for a project and want to find the position of a given element on the page. Basically I want to do what Quirksmode findPos() does:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

I've looked through Google's documentation for positioning:

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_positioning.html

...but I can't find anything related to obtaining an element's current position. **Does the library provide a solution or should I resort to native javascript to handle this?**

Comment: why not .position or .offset function of a jQuery? Seems like what you ned

Comment: Because the project I'm working on is using closure and not jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you're looking for resides in `goog.style`, I'm pretty sure [`goog.style.getPageOffset`](http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/namespace_goog_style.html#getPageOffset) is what you want.